# How to convert Timezones in Double?

Tags: android, timezone

Can anyone tell me how to get Timezones in double, actually I get timezone like this way `UTC+5.30`. But I want only 5.30 in double.

Comment: `return Double.parseDouble("UTC+5.30".substring(3))`?

Comment: Why the heck would you want that?  5 hours and 30 minutes is not at all the same thing as 5.3 hours...  and See also, "Time zone != offset" in the [timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try**

```
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
    String gmt = TimeZone.getTimeZone(tz.getID()).getDisplayName(false,
            TimeZone.SHORT);
    String z1 = gmt.substring(4);

    String z = z1.replaceAll(":", ".");
    double zo = Double.parseDouble(z);
    Log.d("double time", "" + zo);
```